# an or condition in a switch case

Tags: switch-statement, case, xpages-ssjs

I execute some SSJS code that I have a switch statement in that looks something like this

```
switch (form){
        case ("frmContract" || "frmLease") :
           //do some stuff
           return;
           break;
        case "frmSomethingElse" :
          //do something else
          return;
          break
}
```

however, the or statement in the case does not work. It seems to be ignored frmContract and frmLease. Is there a way to do this in a switch or do I need to do it with if statements

Comment: Put each case on a separate `case` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put an '`||`' (or) use this:

```
switch (form){
        case "frmContract" : case "frmLease" :
           //do some stuff
           return;
           break;
        case "frmSomethingElse" :
          //do something else
          return;
          break
}
```

To put an '`&&`' (and) try using a method... I don't know...

```
bool Cmp(){
if("this"&&"this") { //Do stuff and finally 
return true;
}
else { return false; } //Nothing done
}



switch (form){
        case "frmContract":
           if(Cmp()) //<- Don't worry about Lease being true or not...
                     //Cmp will make this... If both are true, will make something
           else
           //do some stuff
           return;
           break;
        case "frmLease":
           if(Cmp()); //<- Don't worry about Lease being true or not...
                     //Cmp will make this... If both are true, will make something,
           else
           //do some stuff
           return;
           break;
        case "frmSomethingElse" :
          //do something else
          return;
          break
   }
```

Comment: A switch capable type, can't fulfill two case's at any one time, so there is no && usecase.

Comment: If he wants to know if X&&Y were selected, then create a Function that inside checks this: if(X && Y) { Do something } else {//NOTHING} and place it when X or Y is selected and run the FUnction
As I made this a bool, it will return true if it succesfully found X&&Y, else returns false and do stuff just for X or Y. Switch does't have &&, then use the head and create your "and" for the switch. It's easy. Maybe it doesn't have any use but that's what he asked.

Comment: He only asked for an or condition. Variable F can't be both X && Y at the same time, it may be X || Y though.

Comment: @c_str the syntax case "frmContract" : "frmLease" : makes more sense than having them on separate lines - just visually more intuitive even it is functionally the same.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you list a case for a switch, the break; ends the execution of the switch statement. If you choose not to include the break, it will continue on to the next case statement until it sees a break; or return; If you list two case's in a row, with no break it will basically server the purpose of the or statement. You could also utilize the default: statement depending on the usecase.

```
switch (form){
        case "frmContract":
        case "frmLease":
           //do some stuff
           return;
           break;
        case "frmSomethingElse" :
          //do something else
          return;
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var form="frmContract";
```

switch  (form)

{

```
        case "frmContract":

       //do some stuff
       break;
       case "frmLease":
      //do something else
      break;
      case "frmSomethingElse":
      //do something else
      break;
```

}